# Lazy access to React context in callbacks

Tags: reactjs, react-context, react-leaflet

I trying to optimize an application that uses react-leaflet. To get the map, you are expected to call `useLeaflet`. Problem: the L object changes a lot, so this hook is too generic.
You can have a similar issue with `useRouter` from Next.js for instance: it will make your component rerender for any route change. So if you store some changing data in the route query, you may have unexpected renders.

A way to bypass this is to call the hook higher up... which totally defeat the purpose of a global context.

I'd like to find away to be able to call context hooks in callbacks instead. After all, the context lives in one place, so there is no reason (from my naive point of view) it couldn't be accessed on the fly.
This would be especially useful in callbacks, for instance to call `L.map.fitBounds`, or to access the current route query etc. etc.

Mandatory code sample, those callbacks allow me to fit the view on a selected rectangle, and to update this rectangle:

```
  const L = useLeaflet();
  // if an area is selected, fit it on first mount
  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedArea) {
      L.map.fitBounds(rectBoundsToLatLng(selectedArea));
    }
  }, []);

  const selectCurrentArea = useCallback(() => {
    selectArea(latLngToRectBounds(L.map.getBounds()));
    deactivateManualSelection();
  }, [L.map.getBounds]);
  const fitCurrentArea = useCallback(() => {
    L.map.fitBounds(rectBoundsToLatLng(selectedArea));
  }, [L.map.fitBounds]);
```

This is kinda dull, because those callback needs to be defined very high up to avoid to many rerender of the child component due to `useLeaflet()`. Calling the context on the fly in the callback would be more efficient IMO.

Is there an escape hatch that would allow to handle such scenarios? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

I'd try memoizing the `L` and updating the reference only on certain updates you are interested in and stuff the memoized value in context:

```
const LeafletContext = React.createContext()
// outside of component

const L = useLeaflet();
const memoizedL = useMemo(() => L, [L.map.getBounds, L.map.fitBounds])
return <LeafletContext.Provider value={memoizedL}>{/* children */}</LeafletContext.Provider>
```

And then using this `L` from context via hook `useContext(LeafletContext)`

Similiarly, you could achieve this by wrapping the Leaflet in `useRef` and then using this `ref` in your callbacks to avoid reference updates

Comment: I indeed had the idea of the ref, but how do you access it? You are back to prop drilling, because the component that need "L" is below in the tree, and if you put the ref in the context. I'll wait a little for other answer but otherwise I think it make sense. I could maybe make an helper to facilitate creating new, more precise context out of a broader context.

Comment: I think that since `useLeaflet` is already context-based, you can move this `useMemo` thing to the custom hook which composes `useLeaflet` and `useMemo`

Comment: It probably could have an API like `useLeafletField(["map.getBounds", "map.fitBounds"])`, I guess this would work and prevent a rerender, will try